# Is there a way to make a list of arrays, sorted out from first column?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have to make a list of arrays grouped out from the first column number. This is using numpy.
I have following array; x. The first column shows how the arrays  should be organized with the numbers 0,1,3 and 4.

```
x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,3],
              [1,0,0,2,3],
              [4,0,0,0,0],
              [3,0,0,0,2],
              [0,0,0,0,3],
              [1,0,0,2,3]])
```

I found out how to sort the array:

```
data = x[np.argsort(x[:, 0])]
print(data)
[[0 0 0 0 3]
 [0 0 0 0 3]
 [1 0 0 2 3]
 [1 0 0 2 3]
 [3 0 0 0 2]
 [4 0 0 0 0]]
```

But the output has to be a list with elements of arrays
like this:

```
list_of_arrays = np.array([[[0,0,0,3],
                            [0,0,0,3]], 
                           [[0,0,2,3],[0,0,2,3]], 
                           [[0,0,0,2]],
                           [[0,0,0,0]]])
```

So the first column works as a marker for how the arrays should look like in the list.
I'm pretty new to python and coding in general, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
[np.row_stack(x[np.where(x[:, 0] == y)])[:, 1:] for y in set(x[:, 0])]
```

```
[array([[0, 0, 0, 3],
        [0, 0, 0, 3]]),
 array([[0, 0, 2, 3],
        [0, 0, 2, 3]]),
 array([[0, 0, 0, 2]]),
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

Explanation: this is a list comprehension where `set()` will first pick all unique values from the first matrix column. The comprehension goes through all those values, and `np.where` finds indices of rows starting with each value. The first column of each row is then removed by the slice expression and the rows are grouped by `row_stack()` into arrays.

Comment: I hghly doubt that this will do the grouping as requested above.

Comment: there is not a third dimension - the results are grouped by the 1st (now removed) order number

Comment: ah, now I understand

Answer (score 0):

You would need to groupy the first value, then you can create new arrays with fromiter and resize them accordingly and reassamble into an array:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain, groupby, tee

x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,3],
              [1,0,0,2,3],
              [4,0,0,0,0],
              [3,0,0,0,2],
              [0,0,0,0,3],
              [1,0,0,2,3]])


def fromiter2d_drop_first(it, dtype):
    # modified from
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45738134/7505395 
    it, it2 = tee(it)
    length = sum(1 for _ in it2) 

    flattened = chain.from_iterable(it)
    array_1d = np.fromiter(flattened, dtype)
    array_2d = np.reshape(array_1d, (length, -1))
    return array_2d [:, 1:]


data = x[np.argsort(x[:, 0])]
groups = np.array( [fromiter2d_drop_first(v, int) 
                    for k,v in groupby(data, key=lambda i:i[0])], dtype=object)
print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[array([[0, 0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0, 3]])
 array([[0, 0, 2, 3], [0, 0, 2, 3]]) 
 array([[0, 0, 0, 2]])
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
This might help you out:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,3],
              [1,0,0,2,3],
              [4,0,0,0,0],
              [3,0,0,0,2],
              [0,0,0,0,3],
              [1,0,0,2,3]])

def get_arr_lists(iterr):
    tmp_list = []
    for val in iterr:
        tmp_list.append(val[1:])
    return tmp_list

data = x[np.argsort(x[:, 0])]

final_arr = [get_arr_lists(iterr) for x, iterr in groupby(data, key = itemgetter(0))]

print(final_arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [array([0, 0, 0, 3]), array([0, 0, 0, 3])], 
    [array([0, 0, 2, 3]), array([0, 0, 2, 3])], 
    [array([0, 0, 0, 2])], 
    [array([0, 0, 0, 0])]
]
```